# How can I extract the CPU percentage value of a process (object)?

Tags: powershell, process, cpu, percentage

I'm trying to get the CPU % of a process, so I can restart it if it exceeds a certain percentage, but I'm stuck trying to extract it from an object in PowerShell. Here is an example code:

```
$ProcessName = “LightingService”
$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Samples = (Get-Counter “\Process($Processname*)\% Processor Time”).CounterSamples
$Samples | Select InstanceName,
    @{Name=”CPU %”;Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}}
```

which outputs something like

```
InstanceName    CPU %
------------    -----
lightingservice  1.76
```

but I only need the "1.76" value, . Can someone help me extract that value out? Or know any easier way to get the CPU % shown in Task Manager?

Comment: Try `[Decimal]::Round(($Samples.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)` instead of `$Samples | Select ...`

Comment: Wow, thanks. That works perfectly.